# How to break down an array of objects within a string

Tags: javascript

I have some code that returns something like this:

```
body: '[
    {
        name: "name",
        lastname: "lastname"
    },
    {
        name: "name",
        lastname: "lastname"
    },
    {
        name: "name",
        lastname: "lastname"
    }
]'
```

Of course extracting the body is a simple `object.body` however, to get rid of the `''` that wraps the array is just destroying me. I tried doing `object.body.slice(1,-1)` to get rid of them, it didnt work. I'm clearly not using the object properly.

How can I "extract" the array from within the body into a usable array?

Comment: Where is that data coming from? Can you control its form? If you would get valid JSON, you could use `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a valid [JSON](http://json.org/) string, you could just parse the string for an object with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), if you have .

```
array = JSON.parse(string);
```

Comment: You can't do that, since the keys are not quoted.

Comment: You Ninja'd me :-(

Comment: Parse actually worked. I apologize for the RIDICULOUSLY STUPID question. been coding for 9 hrs straight today and my brain just can't process anymore. I'll accept the answer asap and upvote all of you friends :)

Comment: @GalAppelbaum Either the string you've posted in your question doesn't reflect your actual data, or `JSON.parse` won't work. The string in the question is not valid JSON, since the keys of the objects are not enclosed in double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to *evaluate* the content of the string. Assuming whatever code building this string can't actually build JS objects to begin with, you can use `eval` or `Function` to generate the objects you need.

```
var data = eval(string);
```

Note that you *must* be sure that the source of the string is safe and reliable, otherwise you could be evaluating ***malicious code***. There may also be performance consequences to using `eval`.

Using `Function` is a *tiny bit* safer, only because the code can not access your local variables. It should also avoid the performance costs of `eval`.

```
var data = Function("return (" + string + ");")();
```

Same warning about malicious code though.

---

If the string data was valid JSON, you could use `JSON.parse`, but it isn't, so you can't. To avoid security issues, either have the source provide valid JSON data, or write your own minimal parser to parse the data.

Comment: There must be another way. `eval` is *never* a good idea, not even if you're 100% sure (because you can't be)

Comment: @Aenadon: `eval/Function` is a very good idea in those circumstances where you can guarantee safety. Don't play the *"never"* game. Instead be informed. My answer gives the necessary warnings.

Comment: @Aenadon in this situation this is a good idea. `Eval` will interpret the string to generate a array based on the string.

Comment: No! `eval` should never be used without sanitizing the given parameter!

Comment: @lumio: `eval` is a useful tool, as long as you know when to use it. Knowledgeable programmers don't need to resort to these knee-jerk reactions. You do yourself and others a disservice with such extreme overreactions.

Comment: Depending on the input source it can but should not be used - especially when you are dealing with data that can be changed by others. Always parse data or run it in a sandbox (like [NodeJS VM](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html))

Comment: And there is a reason for such a reaction.

Comment: @lumio: My answer gives the warning about malicious code. If the source is secure, there's no problem. If you can't guarantee the source, then it shouldn't be used. It's the same as linking to external scripts. No difference. You don't download and run anything without trusting the source. Are you also against loading external scripts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use split function and then take the first element, let me say

```
var a = '[{name: "name",lastname: "lastname"},{name: "name",lastname: "lastname"},{name: "name",lastname: "lastname"}]';
    var s = a.split("'");
```

s[0] will return you the desired result

Comment: The variable `a` does not contain single quote `'`. What are you splitting then?

Comment: sorry, it's my mistake! What i mean is that suppose var a is a string containing those single quotes as your situation is!
so in this case 
var a = '\'[{name: "name",lastname: "lastname"},{name: "name",lastname: "lastname"},{name: "name",lastname: "lastname"}]\'';
var s = a.split("'");
s[1] will be the wanted result!